# How to diagnose horn malfunction?

Tags: toyota, tacoma, horn

07 Toyota Tacoma,
Horn stopped working altogether after working fine (no intermittency).
Fuse is fine and when I jump the relay with a tool the horn activates.  Tried replacing the relay and it’s still the same problem.

Am I not getting power to the relay?  Why would that be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I think your next stop is the horn button. You've already proven the horn and relay work, so power is not an issue and it is physically in good shape. The only thing else you've got at this point (to my line of thinking) is the button itself, which means tearing the steering wheel apart and test the button itself. Test the button for continuity when closed (when you push on it) and you can also check to see if powering the circuit from the steering wheel end will cause the horn to function.

You'll need to be careful with the airbag system. Ensure everything is completely powered down before you tear it apart or you run the risk of it blowing up in your face.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a safer option to Paul's answer. Remove the relay, and using a multimeter, check for 12v between the power and ground pins (85/86) on the socket when the horn button is pressed (you'll need an assistant...)